# Interceptor not wrapping JAX-RS sub-resource endpoint methods

Tags: java, jax-rs, interceptor

Payara 5, Jersey 2.37, JAX-RS 2.1

I'm attempting to create a logging "transaction,"  where a REST endpoint (either sub-resource method or terminal endpoint - I'll demonstrate both below) is annotated with a custom interceptor.  This works fine when the annotated method is on a root resource class, but fails on a sub-resource method. I understand why, and I'll walk through the process below, but I can't figure out how to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve.

First, here is the interceptor classes:

```java
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Audited {

    @Nonbinding
    String description() default "";

}

@Audited
@Interceptor
public class AuditedInterceptor implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private AuditedTransactionBeanLocal trx;
    
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        
        Audited audit = getAnnotation(context);

        trx.beginOrJoin()

        Object o = context.proceed();

        trx.end();
    
        return o;

    }

    private Audited getAnnotation(InvocationContext context) {
        Method m = context.getMethod();
        return (m.isAnnotationPresent(Audited.class)) ? 
               m.getAnnotation(Audited.class):
               context.getTarget().getClass().getAnnotation(Audited.class);
    }
}
```

Here's an example endpoint:

```java
@RequestScoped
@Path("/foo")
public class FooFacade {

    @Inject
    private BarBeanLocal barBean;

    @Path("/do-something")
    @Audited(description = "Foo Do Something (root) - works")
    public Response barFacade(@QueryParam("i") Integer i) {
            return Response.accepted(barBean.doSomething(i)).build();
    }

    @Path("/bar")
    @Audited(description = "Bar Audit (root) - doesn't wrap returned sub resource")
    public BarFacade barFacade() {
            return new BarFacade();
    }

}

public class BarFacade {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Audited(description = "Bar Audit Post (sub resource) - never triggered")
    public Response post(BarRequest payload) {
        BarResponse response = barBean.run(payload);
        return Response.accepted(response).build();
    }

}
```

The EJBs "requests" an audit action during their processing, which is handled by `AuditedTransactionBeanLocal`. I won't go into detail on that, but assume that audits can be nested, and the audit tree is managed by that bean.

Here is an example bean participating in that audit.

```java
@Local
public interface FooBarBeanLocal {
   
    Integer doSomething();
    BarResponse run(BarRequest request);
}

@Stateless
public class FooBarBean implements FooBarBeanLocal, Serializable {

    @Inject
    private AuditedTransactionBeanLocal trx;

    @Override
    Integer doSomething(Integer i) {
        Integer r = i * 2;
        trx.audit(String.format("%02d yielded %02d", i, r)); 
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    BarResponse run(BarRequest request) {
        trx.audit("Bar run called with these values blah blah blah");              
        return new BarResponse("ok");
    }

}
```

The clear problem is that the initial sub resource method interceptor completes it's transaction before any sub resource methods are called:

```java
        Audited audit = getAnnotationFromContext(context);

        trx.beginOrJoin()

        // Here, "o" is an instance of BarFacade
        Object o = context.proceed();

        // END THE CURRENT TRANSACTION BEFORE ANY BarFacade methods are called!!
        trx.end();
    
        return o;  // We are no longer being audited
```

Of course, I can't just annotation the sub resource with `Audited` because it's not a container managed resource and it will just be ignored.

How to solve this issue?  I'm going to go back and read the spec, but I thought I saw something about using a `@Provider` filter.  Is that how JAX-RS sniffs out endpoints on sub resources?  Is that filter type only called on JAX-RS endpoints (which will allow me to inspect/manage it like an interceptor)?

---

According to the JAX-RS 2.1 spec, Chapter 4.1 "Lifecycle and Environment":

> By default a single instance of each provider class is instantiated
> for each JAX-RS application.

So, I'm not sure how a Provider filter could work in the context of request/session scope.

---

My current thought process on this after reading the spec could be to implement a `@Profider` filter, like such:

```
@Provider
public class AuditedFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter,
ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Inject
    private AuditedTransactionBeanLocal trx;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        trx.beginOrJoin();

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        trx.end();

    }

}
```

This presents some complications.  First, since `@Audited` not specifically an endpoint interceptor (remember that I want to allow nested), EJB methods can also be annotated with `@Audited` to nest their sub-process.  In the filter, I could test if the method is `@Audited` and begin the "transaction," but interceptors on resource methods will also initiate a transaction.  And if I remove the `@Audited` from locator methods and only put them on terminal methods (either root resource or sub class), I have to know which it is so I know if I need to initiate a transaction.

Confused! :)

---

The following doesn't work either:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/foo")
public class FooFacade {

    @Inject
    private BarBeanLocal barBean;
    
    @Context
    private ResourceContext rc;

    @Path("/bar")
    public BarFacade barFacade() {
            return rc.initResource(new BarFacade());
    }

}


public class BarFacade {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Audited(description = "Bar Audit Post (sub resource) - never triggered")
    public Response post(BarRequest payload) {
        BarResponse response = barBean.run(payload);
        return Response.accepted(response).build();
    }

}
```